# Why can't invoke the function defined in prototype of a function?

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I've some javascript code:

```
wzq.CategoryTree = function(config) {
};
wzq.CategoryTree.prototype.hello = function() {
    alert("Hello");
};

var categoryTree = new wzq.CategoryTree({});
categoryTree.hello();
```

I think it should alert a "Hello" message box, but nothing happened. Where is wrong?

---

**UPDATE**

Sorry, guys, I missed something important from the working code, the `CategoryTree` should be:

```
wzq.CategoryTree = function(config) {
     return new Ext.tree.TreePanel();
};
```

So:

```
var categoryTree = new wzq.CategoryTree({});
```

It's actually a `Ext.tree.TreePanel` not a `CategoryTree`, that's why no `hello` can be found.

Comment: assuming a wzq object was created earlier, the code will function like you expect it to do.

Comment: Please post a full working example of the problem.

Comment: @RightSaidFred, you are right, this example missed something import from the working one. I updated it now.

Comment: @Freewind silly doubt .. but from where Ext.tree.TreePanel is coming ? Sencha ?

Comment: @Chris thanks again for concern , i am just building the momentum ,since i am freelancer i have to read a lot of stackoverflow question & i don't want to loose track of them. So by engaging with editing anything , i try keep track & learn pragmatically .  Note: I have no craving for reputation point that is least concern , I am Geek .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is `wzq` defined? Running your code yields an `Uncaught ReferenceError: wzq is not defined`.

This works: ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tUUYn/))

```
wzq = {};

wzq.CategoryTree = function(config) {
};
wzq.CategoryTree.prototype.hello = function() {
    alert("Hello");
};

var categoryTree = new wzq.CategoryTree({});
categoryTree.hello();
```